# How to have an element above a certain div but below it's child?

Tags: html, css, positioning, z-index

```
<div class="one"><div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to have the div with class of one to be above the parent div but below the child div?

Comment: Yes, this is css modifications. review positions tags (absolute)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible

[here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="one"> 1 </div>

<div class="parent">
    parent
    <br/>    <br/>    <br/>    <br/>
  <div class="child">
      child
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.one{
    background:yellow;
    height:30px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
}

.parent{
       background:green;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
}

.child{
     background:black;
    height:100px;
    width:60px;
}
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle leads to the jsfiddle homepage.

Comment: That doesn't do what I want. If you give the div with a class of one to have a top of 100px, it is over the child. I want it to be below the child but above the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what about that:

**HTML**

```
<div class="one">One
</div>

<div class="parent">Parent
  <div class="child">Child
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.one {
    margin-top: 100px;
    background: blue;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
}

.parent {
    background: yellow;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;

}
.child {
    position: absolute;
    background: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    top: -300px;
}
```

Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4hyDs/).

Answer (score 0):

This way is even shorter:

```
.one { margin-top: 100px; }
.child { width: 100%; height: 100px; position: absolute; top: 0; }
```

See an example here: http://codepen.io/zitrusfrisch/pen/AzBfv